# Firebase/JWT php plugin to create ECDH-ES+A256KW token

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

i use [this site](https://dinochiesa.github.io) to create JWT token and now i want to create that in php code with [firebase](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) plugin but i have to change algoritm & encrypt like the photo below + with a specific public key:

[image]

the simple code for creating JWT in this plugin is like this:

```
$secretKey = 'key';
$payload = [
  'iss' => 'http://test.com', // refer site
  'iat' => time(), //  token generate
  'nbf' => time()+30, /// token usable after 
  'exp' => time()+36000, /// token expire
  $data = ['email' => $email] 
];
$jsonWebToken = JWT::encode($payload,$secretKey,'HS256');
```

so how i must change the code to generate that key?!

Comment: Firebase\JWT seems to support only JWS, but you need JWE.